# Wordpress rest_cookie_invalid_nonce 403

Tags: wordpress

I have exported a wordpress website to another domains and all working fine except fot some ajax request I am doing that are using WP nonce.

now when I execute the ajax POST I get this error:

responseJSON: Object { code: "rest_cookie_invalid_nonce", message: "Cookie check failed", data: { status: 403 } }

I am creating the nonce and is beeing added to the request properly.
As I said. It works on the development domain but doesn't work on the final domain.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is related to your cache system.
The nonce is valid only for 12h, so you must be sure that the page that generate it is not cached for a time longer of 12h.
Best